# In VBA, when I change the format of one column, the adjacent one changes too

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to format two columns - one as "General" and one as "Number 0.000," but when the second one formats, it changes the format of the first column to "Number 0.000" as well. If I manually select the columns and change the format it works fine. Why is my macro changing the format of both columns?

Here is a code snippet:

```
Range("C:C").Select
Selection.NumberFormat = "General"
Range("D:D").Select
Selection.NumberFormat = "0.000"
```

Comment: The code you've shared should work.  Is there any additional code before/after those lines that could be hiding the real problem?

Comment: @padawan0007 - I'm pretty sure what's happening is that somehow in between the `.select` and `selection.numberformat...` lines, he's selecting other cells, or keeping C selected when D gets selected.  I think avoiding `.select` will solve his issue.

Comment: Yeah, that's what it looks like to me, too.  I just wondered where that could be happening.  I definitely agree that avoiding `.Select` like the plague is best, but it seems odd that these 4 lines could allow for any ambiguity as to what is actually selected. He's not adding to an existing selection or anything like that.

Answer (score 2):

Try to avoid using `.Select`, it might cause issues.  Try:

```
Range("C:C").NumberFormat = "General"
Range("D:D").NumberFormat = "0.000"
```

That works for me.

The reason it works if you manually select the range is because when you select a range, the `.select` part in your macro will use what is selected.  Avoiding `.select` helps to ensure that no matter what cell/range you have selected, it will use the explicit range you want (in this case, Range("C:C") and Range("D:D")).